# Cron every day at 6 pm

Tags: cron

I'm trying to figure out how to set cron to run every day at 6 p.m. Is this correct?

The reason I'm asking is this is for a production server, so I need to be sure.

```
* 18 * * *
```

Comment: There are many things that can go wrong with cron jobs on a production server. Be sure to test it, maybe with a "dry run" command first.

Comment: @Thilo I have a duplicate virtual machine I was planning on testing it on. Thank you for your advice!!

Comment: see https://crontab.guru/#0_18_*_*_* (_I am not related to the site_)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm will help us understand cron expressions clearly

Answer (score 137, accepted):

```
0 18 * * * command to be executed
^ you need to set the minute, too. Else it would be running every minute on the 18th hour
```

***How to setup a cronjob in general:***

```
 # * * * * *  command to execute
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
 # │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
 # │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
 # │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
 # └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

**What does Asterisk (*) mean**

The asterisk indicates that the cron expression matches for all values of the field. E.g., using an asterisk in the 4th field (month) indicates every month.

**Sidenote**

Other special characters in cronjobs

**Slash ( / )**

Slashes describe increments of ranges. For example 3-59/15 in the 1st field (minutes) indicate the third minute of the hour and every 15 minutes thereafter. The form "*/..." is equivalent to the form "first-last/...", that is, an increment over the largest possible range of the field.

**Comma ( , )**

Commas are used to separate items of a list. For example, using "MON,WED,FRI" in the 5th field (day of week) means Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays.

**Hyphen ( - )**

Hyphens define ranges. For example, 2000-2010 indicates every year between 2000 and 2010 AD, inclusive.

**Percent ( % )**

Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (), are changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % are sent to the command as standard input.

*(source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)*

Answer (score 21):

You should use:

`0   18  *   *   *`

This would execute the cron at the 0th minute at 6 PM. You can [use a tool like this one](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jslibrary/demos/crontab.php) in the future.