# Java Application failing to execute because of time zone issue

Tags: java, date, timezone

I have written a Java Program which takes the current IST timing and generates a report. This report should to be generated at 6pm IST, this check is done in the code itself after fetching IST timezone:

```
Date dateStr = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")).getTime();
```

Problem Area: We are executing that java file in the server in PD timezone and the app is failing and no report is generated because dateStr value is being overwritten by the PD time zone.

Please help me with this as I am not clear like why PD time is shown when I am using IST time in date variable from the code.

Comment: use **cron scheduler**. refer this answer **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221438/cron-every-day-at-6pm**

Comment: Your code line could be shortened to the equivalent expression `Date dateStr = new Date();` because you just query the current time which does not depend on any timezone.

Comment: Thanks @MenoHochschild I got the issue now. I've set the timezone for SimpleDateFormat to IST and converted the date object (where Date date = new Date())

Comment: Exactly, if you want to or must use such an old Time-API then it is best practice not to rely on `java.util.Date.toString()` but to use a properly zoned instance of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `dateStr` variable is not being overwritten by any timezone, because a `java.util.Date` doesn't have any timezone information.

What it does, though, is to **use** the JVM default timezone when you print it: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Either you `System.out.println` it, or log it with your favorite logging API (such as `log.info(date)`), or even check its value in a debugger. All of those implicity calls `toString()`, and this method just "converts" the date to the JVM default timezone (actually, the `Date` object doesn't change, just the `String`).

If you want a timezone-aware object, you could use the `Calendar` instance. Or even better, if you have Java 8 or higher, just go with the [date/time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

By the way, as said in the comments, `Calendar.getInstance(timezone).getTime()` will return the same as `new Date()`, so you must include more code in your question, showing how you're using the date, otherwise we can't know what you're doing and how to fix it.