# How to schedule background tasks in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have been looking a lot for this but haven't found any packages or a way to schedule background tasks in Flutter. Like in Android there is `WorkManager`,`AlarmManager`.

I know I can access those classes using `MethodChannel`, but I want something that works for iOS and Android both.

(Its very disappointing that a mobile framework doesn't have the ability to schedule background tasks).

Comment: Perhaps the `alarm_manager` packages is what you are looking for, but Afaik it's being reworked currently to work with the latest Flutter version.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer does it support both iOS and Android? and can you provide me a link to the project?

Comment: The new version will. I don't know about the current one. I'm not sure what the progress on the new one is. Didn't follow closely. I guess it's a bit stalled because of vacation season.

Comment: If you need to schedule some computation (eg. background task) then you can use any scheduler. If you need to know how to execute background tasks then you need to ask about how to execute them. When you will know how to execute them then you can easy schedule them. What you want to know?

Answer (score 33):

There is a [Medium blogpost](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124) that explains how to do this.
However we thought it was way too complicated to set up so it just happens we created a [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) that aids you with this.

```
//Provide a top level function or static function.
//This function will be called by Android and will return the value you provided when you registered the task.
//See below
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task) {
    print("Native echoed: $task");
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

Workmanager.initialize(
    callbackDispatcher, //the top level function.
    isInDebugMode: true //If enabled it will post a notification whenever the job is running. Handy for debugging jobs
)
```

We support Android's Workmanager and iOS performFetch

---

For now it only works for Android project, but we are looking at iOS soon.
I'll update this answer when it is available.

---

We have iOS support now too. It is still early alpha, but give a go.
We wrote a complimentary [Medium](https://medium.com/vrt-digital-studio/flutter-workmanager-81e0cfbd6f6e) post too.

Comment: There are solutions for android out there, but I am looking for something that works for both iOS and Android. I have talked to quite a lot of developers who are looking for solution to this problem.

Comment: We are actually in the process of supporting iOS in an upcoming release.

Comment: @GurleenSethi We updated the library to support iOS take a look.

Comment: Here's one. https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch. The one written by Tim is probably the best but it's GPL 3. You need to release your source code for your app!

Comment: is one-off-task availabe in ios?

Comment: can we use Workmanager plugin to registerPeriodicTask with frequency of 1 sec.?  As per doc., 'Minimum frequency is 15 min'

Comment: android_alarm_manager and workmanager. Between these which is able to run tasks even when the app is slide/closed from the ram?

Comment: hey in what durations it runs the background task?

Comment: So will this work If I cleared the app from recent?

Comment: On of earlier comments here mention it is GPL 3. It is now MIT.

Answer (score 16):

**SOLUTION 1:** [android_alarm_manager_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus) is the best solution to schedule background tasks. But the only **disadvantage** is only support  Android.

**Note:** *if you are using **android_alarm_manager** version, please migrate to the Plus version :D*

Let's start:

After importing this plugin to your project as usual, add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml within the  tags:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Next, within the  tags, add:

```
<service
    android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
    android:exported="false"/>
<receiver
    android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false"/>
<receiver
    android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then in Dart code add:

```
import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';

void printHello() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
  print("[$now] Hello, world! isolate=${isolateId} function='$printHello'");
}

main() async {
  final int helloAlarmID = 0;
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(...);
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 1), helloAlarmID, printHello);
}
```

If you want to schedule any task every day at a specific time, you need to do something like this:

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
   await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
      const Duration(hours: 24), //Do the same every 24 hours
      helloAlarmID, //Different ID for each alarm
      printHello,
      wakeup: true, //the device will be woken up when the alarm fires
      startAt: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day, 5, 0), //Start whit the specific time 5:00 am
      rescheduleOnReboot: true, //Work after reboot
   );
}
```

If alarm callbacks will need access to other Flutter plugins, including the alarm manager plugin itself, it may be necessary to inform the background service how to initialize plugins depending on which Flutter Android embedding the application is using.

This is done by giving the AlarmService a callback to call the application's onCreate method.

In particular, its Application class is as follows:

```
public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AlarmService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        //add AndroidAlarmManagerPlugin plugin register  if you work with arlarm
        AndroidAlarmManagerPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AndroidAlarmManagerPlugin"));
    }
}
```

Which must be reflected in the application's AndroidManifest.xml. E.g.:

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        ...
```

- 

**SOLUTION 2:**
[Cron](https://pub.dev/packages/cron) is another best solution to schedule background tasks. Cron run tasks periodically at fixed times, dates or intervals. But the onliy **disadvantage** of corn is once the app kill, cron not working in background as expected.

A simple usage example:

```
import 'package:cron/cron.dart';

main() {
  var cron = new Cron();
  cron.schedule(new Schedule.parse('*/3 * * * *'), () async {
    print('every three minutes');
  });
  cron.schedule(new Schedule.parse('8-11 * * * *'), () async {
    print('between every 8 and 11 minutes');
  });
}
```

How to setup a cronjob in general: [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221438/cron-every-day-at-6-pm)

Test cronjob: [crontab](https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_*)

Comment: Agreed with, but once app kill , the `cron` not working in background as expected the `WorkManager`

Comment: I realized about it after using it, but already added another solution, good day. :)

Comment: android_alarm_manager and workmanager. Between these which is able to run tasks even when the app is slide/closed from the ram?

Comment: [User this](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus) one, the given is deprecated

Comment: Yes, you'ŕe right, i will update my answer becasue 'android_alarm_manager' plugin has been replaced by the android_alarm_manager_plus. No further updates are planned to this plugin, and we encourage all users to migrate to the Plus version.

Answer (score 4):

Use `WorkManager` lib

```
dependencies:
  workmanager: ^0.2.3
```

`WorkManager` comes under two parts, which run the task in the background.

**1. Delayed background work**

registerOneOffTask runs the task only once with an initial delay of 10 seconds. This is useful when we need to perform any background work only once.

**Example:**

```
Workmanager.registerOneOffTask(
  "1",
  "registerOneOffTask",
  initialDelay: Duration(seconds: 10),
);
```

**2. Periodic background work**

This task runs periodically, Since we have not provided a frequency it will be the default 15 minutes.
**Example:**

```
Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask(
  "2",
  "registerPeriodicTask",
  initialDelay: Duration(seconds: 10),
);
```

Comment: Can i run a function in Periodic task ? @Jitesh Mohite

Comment: @Ashutoshpatole: Ideally you should not, use only callback

Comment: registerPeriodicTask only supports android