# flutter what is the best way to update Firebase every 24 hours automatically?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to update `Firestore` `document` every day at 6 AM automatically.
For instance, there is a quote app and update quote to a new one every morning so that the user can see the different quotes.
I don't mind whether executing code on an iOS device or Android because I have both phones.
But I want an app to update the document even if I'm sleeping.
What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: These seems like something you might want to do server-side rather than client-side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to schedule background tasks in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706265/how-to-schedule-background-tasks-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Good news it is somewhat possible.

## Background Tasks in a nutshell

On `Android` you would use  `WorkManager`. 
You can ask the `Android` framework to schedule your task somewhere in the future (exact hours are not supported).

On `iOS` you enable `Background Fetch` in XCode or manually edit the `Info.plist` file.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fetch</string>
  </array>
</key>
```

[image]

## WorkManager Plugin

Since there is a lot of ceremony to wire everything together there is a handy `Flutter` plugin which helps you.

The [flutter_workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) plugin supports both `WorkManager` and `performFetch` in one unified Dart API.

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((backgroundTask) {
    switch(backgroundTask) {
      case Workmanager.iOSBackgroundTask:
      case "firebaseTask":
        print("You are now in a background Isolate");
        print("Do some work with Firebase");
        Firebase.doSomethingHere();
        break;
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

void main() {
  Workmanager.initialize(callbackDispatcher);
  Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask(
    "1",
    "firebaseTask",
    frequency: Duration(days: 1),
    constraints: WorkManagerConstraintConfig(networkType: NetworkType.connected),
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, in this case you will need use WorkManager on Android. This is a way to use background service for that case. In iOS I don't know how.

I think that is not possible to create background services in Flutter because it's run in other context.

Comment: Is it not a good idea to execute those logic on mobile device? I mean background execution.

Comment: It's a good idea when you have ways to do that. At the moment, I didn't found a way using only Flutter.

Comment: Do you think this would work? [https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/background_fetch