# Flutter/firebase: execute function at specific time

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I execute a function at a specific time with flutter and firebase? I want to allow the user of my app to send messages to other users at a specific time. Right now, they are sent when the message is created, but I would like to allow the user to schedule the message.

Any idea? I have looked at the Timer class of Flutter, but it does not seem to be useful for this.

Comment: You want the app to send the message on behalf on a user. You could schedule a background task on the device, which calls the function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706265/how-to-schedule-background-tasks-in-flutter I don't know if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me handling this on flutter(frontend) will be a bad idea. You can look into firebase cloud function and [scheduling of cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) to achieve the result. For example, you can have a boolean to show/hide the message in your message model and use cloud function to update it accordingly on the scheduled time.

Comment: But this requires an internet connection, can I do that offline?

Comment: But how will you send it offline, you'll require some kind of trigger?

Comment: I don't want to send anything from backend, I need to do some work everyday at 00:00, for example make a local backup from user's date like whatsapp.

Comment: did you check [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) ? I think that will solve your issue.